# readResolve with serialisable doesn't seem to be working

Tags: android, serialization, singleton

I have a singleton class which I am saving and restoring:

```
private void saveData(){
    FileOutputStream saveFile;
    saveFile = this.openFileOutput(STATE_SAVE_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    ObjectOutput output = new ObjectOutputStream(saveFile);
    output.writeObject(deck); 
}


private void restoreData(){
    FileInputStream restoreFile;

    restoreFile = this.openFileInput(STATE_SAVE_FILE_NAME);

    ObjectInput input = new ObjectInputStream(restoreFile);
    deck = (Deck) input.readObject();
}
```

The object deck is a singleton so I have a readRestore method defined in it:

```
private Object readResolve() { 
    return deck; 
}
```

When I save there is definitely data but the restore gives me nothing. Am I missing something?

The save definitely works because I am able to save and restore other objects. Only the singleton is failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That readResolve() method causes the deserialized object to be completely thrown away and the current value of 'deck' to be returned by readObject() instead. If that's not your intention perhaps it should update 'deck' with data from the deserialized object, which is 'this' when in the readResolve() method.

Comment: Why do all the examples show that you just need to return the one you get from returnInstance (or the equivalent)? Example: http://www.oodesign.com/singleton-pattern.html

Comment: @theblitz Your code isn't the same as what's in the link you posted. That example shows how to keep returning the same singleton instance that already exists, so they discard the deserialized object and return getInstance(). You are trying to alter the singleton state via deserialization, but you aren't succeeding, because you are also discarding the serialized object and returning 'deck', which in fact might even still be null. Not at all the same code and not for the same purpose.

Comment: So on the first call I should copy "this" into "deck" and then return that. On subsequent calls just return "deck"?

Comment: @theblitz: I don't know. It depends what you think deserializing a singleton actually means. Only you can decide.